# Jquery select parent li for a given a href

Tags: jquery

Having a variable that can contain '#tab1'..'#tab4', How can I select and change the css style of the corresponding style.

For example: if my variable is tab2; I have only to change the style of the li that have `<a href="#tab2">16 cm</a>`

That's my html code:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">12 cm</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">16 cm</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">19 cm</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">8 cm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to jquery tabs? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Thank you, I have already tabs, I was searching another thing... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply select the a tags by the expected href and then move up to their parents:

```
var yourVariable = "tab2";
var lis = $("a[href='#" + yourVariable + "']").parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.tabs li a[href=#" + yourVariable + "]").parent().css("font-size", "72px");
```